# Windows 7 client machine login without Ad connection

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows-server-2012

We Have a windows server 2012 and client domain machine is windows 7.
The problem is the user can login from the windows 7 machine without the activedirectory connection.So how to prevent this login ?
Is there any policy for prevent login without active directory connection.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default a certain number of logons are cached on the clients (also on servers). You can disable it using a group policy (for example `Default Domain Policy`) and setting `Interactive logon: Number of previous logons to cache (in case domain controller is not available)` in `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options` to `0`. The setting will take effect after a reboot of the clients. Be careful though, employees using laptops and sometimes working from outside the office won't be able to login aswell.